# Remove tuples from dictionary value list if first value in tuple = 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

First I have a dictionary d1 that looks like this:

```
d1 = {    'w' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
          'x' : ['d', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e'],
          'y' : ['f', 'f', 'g'],
          'z' : ['h', 'i']    
     }
```

Then I loop through that dictionary and make a new dictionary in which each value is a list with two elements: an integer and list. The integer is the number of strings in that value in d1. The list contains tuples, each tuple containing a string from d1 (in position 1 of the tuple) and the number of times that string appeared in d1 (in position 0 of the tuple):

```
d2 = {   'w' : [10, [(5, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (2, 'c')], 
         'x' : [5, [(3, 'd'), (2, 'e')],
         'y' : [3, [(2, 'f'), (1, 'g')],
         'z' : [2, [(1, 'h'), (1, 'i')]    
     }
```

I want to remove any string that appears only once ('g', 'h', and 'i'), so in the end I want:

```
dFinal = {    'w' : [10, [(5, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (2, 'c')],
              'x' : [5, [(3, 'd'), (2, 'e')],
              'y' : [2, [(2, 'f')]    
         }
```

I read an example of what I believe is dictionary comprehension to remove whole dictionary items if the length of the value list is less than 2:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(v) > 1}
```

I'm trying to get a grasp on list/dictionary comprehensions and would like to use something like this to achieve what I've described, and learn something along the way.

At first I tried to write a function that took d2 as an argument, but I don't know how to refer to position 0 of each tuple.

Then thought it would probably be much easier to make dFinal using d1, which has no tuples, instead of trying to change d2.

If you could describe a clean way to make dFinal from d1 **and/or** d2, and explain the thought process, I would really appreciate it. Both would really help me understand how to precisely manipulate dictionary lists with comprehensions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use a `Counter` object. Honestly, I would use loops because it will likely be more efficient.

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter
```

**Edit**: Here is how I would actually do this, *without* comprehensions:

```
In [17]: for k,v in d1.items():
    ...:     counts = Counter(v)
    ...:     counts = [t for t in counts.items() if t[1] > 1]
    ...:     if len(counts) > 0:
    ...:         dfinal[k] = [sum(c[1] for c in  counts), counts]
    ...:

In [18]: dfinal
Out[18]:
{'w': [10, [('b', 3), ('a', 5), ('c', 2)]],
 'x': [5, [('d', 3), ('e', 2)]],
 'y': [2, [('f', 2)]]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This doesn't adjust the "sum integer" at the beginning of each value, however. 10, 5, and 3 need to become 10, 5, and 2.

Comment: @ddrsee missed that. Easy fix.

Comment: Thanks a million. I will read about Counter and try to figure out what is going on here...

Comment: This does not preserve the list order, although if that's important it should be pretty trivial to sort.

Comment: @ddrsee a `Counter` object is just a subclass of `dict` specialized for *counting*.

Comment: Yeah, I would do it the same way I did it when I made d2: for k,v in d2.items: v[1].sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0], reverse=True)

Comment: @ddrsee just use `counts = [t for t in counts.most_common() if t[1] > 1]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh neat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is good style, but you can do it like this:

```
dFinal = {k: [sum([i for i, c in v[1] if i != 1]),
              [(i, c) for i, c in v[1] if i != 1]]
          for k, v in d2.items()
          if [(i, c) for i, c in v[1] if i != 1]}
```

Edit: now updates counts.  Again, if the comprehension looks like this, it's time to refactor.

Comment: This doesn't adjust the membership counts `'y': [3, [(2, 'f')]]` although realistically, they probably aren't necessary.

Comment: They are necessary! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have a favorite tutorial on comprehensions like this (and what refactoring is)?

Comment: @ddrsee what Tom is trying to say, I think, is *don't use comprehensions like this*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you talk briefly about the reasons that you shouldn't? I thought they were more efficient than loops but I am very new at this.

Comment: @ddrsee they *can be*, but notice in this case you use `[(i, c) for i, c in v[1] if i != 1]` **three times** in the comprehension. Since you can't store that as an intermediate value, like you can in a loop, three separate lists are created! But you only need to create it once, really, if you think about it. Also, comprehensions like this totally **kill** readability, and that really isn't worth sacrificing for a minor speed gain.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is right about why it is not a good idea to write comprehensions that get this complicated.  Code usually has to be read more often than it is written.  I will not understand the code at a glance six months from now, plus it is less efficient than it could be.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
from collections import Counter

d2 = {k: [len(v), sorted(Counter(v).items())] for k, v in d1.items()}

dFinal = {k: [v1, [(y, x) for x, y in v2 if y > 1]] for k, (v1, v2) in d2.items()}
```

My `d2` and `dFinal` slightly differs from yours. This is my `d2`

```
{'w': [10, [('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('c', 2)]],
 'x': [5, [('d', 3), ('e', 2)]],
 'y': [3, [('f', 2), ('g', 1)]],
 'z': [2, [('h', 1), ('i', 1)]]}
```

this is my `dFinal`

```
{'w': [10, [(5, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (2, 'c')]],
 'x': [5, [(3, 'd'), (2, 'e')]],
 'y': [3, [(2, 'f')]],
 'z': [2, []]}
```

but you can easily fix that yourselves.

btw: I would use functions to make the dictionary and list comprehensions look more easy. Right now it is unreadable.

Comment: To transform `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']` into this `[('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('c', 2)]`.

Comment: You don't need to convert a `Counter` object into a `dict` object to do that. Just remove the call to `dict` and you will see it works exactly the same.

Comment: Yes I updated it. You are right. I am playing with a tiny terminal so I missed it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another option: slower but easier to follow:

```
def has_dupe(lst):
    return any([x[0] > 1 for x in lst[1]])

def reduce_list(lst):
    result = [(x, y) for (x, y) in lst[1] if x > 1]
    return [sum([x for (x, y) in result]), result]

d = {key: reduce_list(value) for key, value in d2.items() if has_dupe(value)}
```